# SQL SERVER 2016 SLOW INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When inserting a block insert starts very fast (3 thousand in 1 second), but as time passes the insertion takes up to 60-70 seconds for every 3 thousand of a total of 8 million records.

Someone knows that I can review:
So far we have verified autogrowth
It checks at disk level, memory and process any increases as to alert something.
It is a VM Ware Virtual Server, Sql server 2016 Enterprise.

Can you help me but I can check over all configurations of the BDD, storage and Server.

table_data_tmp 8 million table identity (used to retrieve) and has an index included
data_table_tmp1 8 million
table_data_tmp1_2 3 mil records
tabla_datos_fin 19 million 30GB - when inserting here the insertion time is slow

Attached Scripts only as a reference because it was already identified that in the insert to the final table is where each time passes it takes to insert

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.INDEXES  WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID( 'tabla_datos_fin') AND NAME = 'IX_tabla_datos_fin_TIP_IDE_1' AND IS_DISABLED =0)
 ALTER INDEX IX_tabla_datos_fin_TIP_IDE_1 ON tabla_datos_fin DISABLE;
GO

TRUNCATE TABLE tabla_datos_tmp


IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.INDEXES  WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID( 'IDX_tabla_datos_tmp') AND NAME = 'tabla_datos_tmp')
DROP INDEX tabla_datos_tmp.IDX_tabla_datos_tmp
GO

INSERT INTO tabla_datos_tmp (campos)
        SELECT *
        FROM [tabla_datos_tmp1] 

CREATE INDEX IDX_tabla_datos_tmp ON tabla_datos_tmp (CONTROL_INT) INCLUDE (all campos)


DECLARE
    @batchsize INT,
    @ctr INT,
    @rc INT,
@val_ini int,
@val_fin int
SELECT
    @batchsize = 3000,
    @ctr = 0;

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN

set @val_ini = @batchsize * @ctr 
set @val_fin =  @batchsize * (@ctr + 1)

truncate table tabla_datos_tmp1_2


INSERT INTO tabla_datos_tmp1_2
(all campos)
SELECT*
FROM tabla_datos_tmp WITH (INDEX =IDX_tabla_datos_tmp )
WHERE CONTROL_INT > @VAL_INI
AND CONTROL_INT <= @VAL_FIN 

UPDATE tabla_datos_tmp1_2 SET FECHA_ULTIMA_ACTUALIZACION= GETDATE ()



/* INSERTION IS DELAYED HERE */
INSERT INTO tabla_datos_fin (al campos)
SELECT *
FROM tabla_datos_tmp1_2 
/**********************/

DELETE  A
FROM tabla_datos_tmp A   WITH (INDEX =IDX_tabla_datos_tmp )
WHERE CONTROL_INT > @VAL_INI AND CONTROL_INT <= @VAL_FIN

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BREAK;

SET @ctr = @ctr + 1;
PRINT @ctr
END

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.INDEXES  WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID( 'tabla_datos_fin') AND NAME = 'IX_tabla_datos_fin' AND IS_DISABLED =1)
 ALTER INDEX IX_tabla_datos_fin ON tabla_datos_fin REBUILD;  
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.INDEXES  WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID( 'tabla_datos_fin') AND NAME = 'IX_tabla_datos_fin_TIP_IDE_1' AND IS_DISABLED =1)
ALTER INDEX IX_tabla_datos_fin_TIP_IDE_1 ON tabla_datos_fin REBUILD;  
GO
```

Comment: What is the initial db file size and filegrowth option? Vmware - with dynamic drive size? Why `truncate table tabla_datos_tmp1_2`, not `@` or `#`?

Answer (score 0):

Use sql server wait stats to see what sql is waiting on.  After you find that, dig into other performance counters until you find the issue.  My guess is your disk cannot keep up.

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/